# How to completely automate UI testing in Android?

Tags: android, testing

Recently we have added some features to our product and are planning for a new release. The issue is, we don't have a dedicated testing team in our organization, so the sole part of testing lies with the development team. Now I bear the responsibility of manually testing all the test-cases and honestly speaking I don't like it.

For each test case, I have to *Login -> Perform some button clicks -> Scroll Up/Down -> Wait for Api Call to finish ->*, etc, etc and then repeat this process for another test case.

**Is there some way I can automate this entire process where all the button clicks, text filling, scrolling, etc is taken care of by some library/framework?**

Comment: There are 2 ways: the first cucumber with Appium and second one is Espresso UI Automator .. check this out: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html

Comment: @TejuVishwakarma okay I'll check this out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to automate tests only for Android, I suggest using Espresso: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/

For both iOS and Android you can find Appium: http://appium.io/

Have a good day, hope it helps :D

Comment: Cool, I'll check this out.

Answer (score 0):

Introducing the easy and powerful framework and tools

The name of the tool / Framework is "Airtest" and if you use it, you can automate Android, iOS, Web, Windows applicaion and so on.

You can find out more at the link below.

https://github.com/AirtestProject/Airtest